# find iPhone places using xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to know my iPhone places using Xcode like this [app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8).I know all the details related to my iPhones.Kindly help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual Find My iPhone implementation details are certainly private and/or using private Apple frameworks (especially as it's a feature that users have to explicitly turn on and off via Settings and there's no user-facing app), but you could use [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html) in an app that you create that runs in the background, reporting your location to some server that your own.

I also found [an alternative app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/is-there-an-alternative-to-find-my-iphone-to-track-a-lost-stolen-iphone-with-sms) named [iLostMyi](http://modmyi.com/cydia/org.thebigboss.ilostmyi), but this requires a jailbroken phone.